# React router 5: restoring scroll position on browser back

Tags: reactjs, react-router

There are similar questions on SO, but react-router versions are different and I did not find an answer that worked for me.

I am trying to restore scroll position in a long page after a user clicks on a router link and hits the browser back button. I expected react-router to handle this, but apparently they have decided to [not handle it at all](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration).

I tried several packages such as [react-scroll-manager](https://github.com/trevorr/react-scroll-manager) and [react-router-scroll](https://github.com/ytase/react-router-scroll), to no avail: when using back, the position is always on top of the document, whether I use Firefox or Chromium.
The page does not load instantly, but it takes less than a second.

Is there any solution that works with react-router-dom 5 BrowserRouter?

Here is the general structure:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <main>
    <h1>...</h1>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='...'
      ...
    </Switch>
  </main>
</BrowserRouter>
```

EDIT: To clarify, the page does not load instantly because there is an AJAX call, which changes the state when it returns, causing a new rendering. I think this is a typical pattern.

Comment: Hi @Damien refer react-router documentation there is a way to scroll on top using HOC
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/scroll-restoration.md

Comment: I know, I am not trying to scroll to the top because it is already doing that. I would like the scroll position that was there when the user clicked the link to be restored (as normally happens with links - this is the behavior users expect).

Comment: i think you need something like https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/scroll-restoration.md#generic-solution
We can write custom click method for all button, link that will take current position as parameter that can be stored in localstorage, redux like a history then from there we can fetch old position and set using styles

Comment: Can you identify why react-scroll-manager doesn't work for you? That is surprising to me. I wrote a similar thing but I suspect it won't work for you for the same reason that react-scroll-manager doesn't (whatever that is): https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-react-router

Comment: @danielnixon: thanks for the link. I tried it but it didn't work either. Maybe there is something wrong with my code. Since you care about accessibility you might be interested in taking a look: https://github.com/MSU-NatSci/DomainAccessibilityAudit

Comment: @danielnixon: Actually I got it to work with oaf-react-router by using `wrapHistory(history, { renderTimeout: 500 });`. I have not seen any documentation about this `renderTimeout` setting, but I saw it in the code. Now if I could just call that code at the right time (after the AJAX call returns) rather than after a pre-determined timeout...

Comment: @Damien Ah, that was the missing piece of information (ajax response required before scroll restoration). A more sophisticated version of that `renderTimeout` hack is something like this: https://medium.com/@gajus/making-the-anchor-links-work-in-spa-applications-618ba2c6954a . Unfortunately oaf-react-router doesn't have that (yet?). See https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-react-router/issues/8

Comment: Another option is to do a `history.replace()` as soon as your ajax response is available. Then later, after the user navigates back, you use the route state to render the page instead of making the ajax request a second time.

Comment: @danielnixon: Could you explain how you would apply that for a general case and give a code example ? This could be a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

So far I found 2 ways to solve this issue for my application, but they might not apply to all projects:

- Use [oaf-react-router](https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-react-router), which also fixes focus to improve accessibility, with the option `wrapHistory(history, { renderTimeout: 500 });`. The drawback is that you have to set that delay, which might not be adapted to all users depending on their connection speed.
- Cache results of AJAX queries along the history path. In my case I simply had to cache the latest result for each different object type. This matches user expectations: the scroll position is restored, and the page content is not updated automatically. But it might not be applicable to all applications.

danielnixon's solution might be a better one in general, but I'm not sure how to implement it:

> Another option is to do a history.replace() as soon as your ajax response is available. Then later, after the user navigates back, you use the route state to render the page instead of making the ajax request a second time.